# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 1072: invalid start byte

Tags: python, csv, numpy, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to open and read a csv file with python but I keep getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openfile.py", line 7 in <module>
    data = csvfile("1.csv")
  File "openfile.py", line 4, in csvfile
    data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter = ",", skiprows =9)
  File "/Users/ZEN/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 880, in loadtxt
    next(fh) 
  File "/Users/ZEN/anaconda/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode 
   (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 1072: invalid start byte
```

I don't know why I can't run this code normally. I'm on python 3.6.0 and Anaconda 4.3.1(x86_64) on a mac. I recently upgraded to python 3.x from 2.x and downloaded numpy.
This is the code I'm trying to run:

```
import numpy as np
def csvfile(filename):
  data = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter = ",", skiprows =9)
  return data

data = csvfile("1.csv")
print (data)
```

It would be great if anyone could help me!

Comment: What encoding is your file using?

Comment: i think the csv file is encoded with unkown-8bit charset

Comment: You won't be able to read the file properly until you know its encoding.

Comment: Technically, you can decode anything (even a JPG image or whatever) with "Latin-1" encoding, without any decoding error. But of course, if that wasn't the right encoding, you'll get garbage in return.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly the coding you are using.

If your data contains Chinese or some special characters, try this

```
data = np.loadtxt(path,encoding="gbk", delimiter=",",dtype="str")
```

If not, generally, using

```
data = np.loadtxt(path,encoding="utf8", delimiter=",",dtype="str")
```

can solve the problem.

**It is important to know the encoding that your file using.**